# Android Studio startActivity

Tags: android

I was searching by myself but failed. Can I start an application like Google translator in the background? Here below-listed program runs the Translator very well, but at the same time, my app goes to the background. I would like to have my app foreground while the Translator is started in the background. Many thanks in advance!

```
Intent app_to_launch = getPackageManager().
            getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.translate");
if (app_to_launch != null) {
    startActivity(app_to_launch);
}
```

Updated:

Following the subject. One thing is observed. Here below-listed code is working fine:

```
            Intent app_to_launch = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.translate");
            if (app_to_launch != null) {
                startActivity(app_to_launch);
            }

            try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch (Exception e){};

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WordsStatus.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

But if I remove the 1 sec pause (Thread.sleep) there is no sign that the Google translator has been run. It seems like the launching of the second Intend (my application starting) suppresses the first launch (Google translator starting). If I restore the 1-sec pause everything works as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure just do this:

```
Intent app_to_launch = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.of.background.app");
            if (app_to_launch != null) {
                startActivity(app_to_launch);
            }
Intent app_to_launch = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.of.forground.app");
            if (app_to_launch != null) {
                startActivity(app_to_launch);
            }
```

(The second app launch doesn't need to use the package manager, you can use anyone of starting an Activity, i.e. if you want to start your own app's internal activity, then just use the normal approach `startActivity(new Intent(this, MyActivity.class))`

That will start two apps, and the second one starting will move the first one second in the stack.

Note that apps don't really "run in the background" any app that isn't showing on the screen is usually in the paused state, (it may have started a background service to do some work though).